# Definition of “definitiveness”. Is there a simple way to tell whether a noun is definite or not?

Tags: articles

“The letter from the company gave **a final warning** that the bill should be paid by the end of the week.” (From Hewings’s “Advanced grammar in use”).

If something is final, how can it be indefinite? What would change if it read “**the** final warning”?

Comment: Part of definiteness is about whether the information is new or old in the discourse. Usually, when a new entity is introduced it is presented as indefinite: if it is presented as definite, this signals that it is already known about, either to the reader, or sometimes (in narrative) to the character in the narrative. Here, _the_ would be possible (for the reason you give), but _a_ is in my view more idiomati.

Comment: @ColinFine That would be a great answer.

Comment: I agree, @ColinFine has the answer. To answer the second question, nothing about the meaning would change by using the definite article, but it might give the sentence a more emphatic feel. I agree that the indefinite is generally the better choice here. If however the context included references to previous warnings, I might favor the definite.

Comment: ------ Hear!Hear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we refer to a person or a thing for the first time in a conversation or a piece of writing, we use indefinite article. Not only English, perhaps all the languages of the world, inherit this art of storytelling from primitive forefathers who after witnessing something / someone new begins like this.

- There was A king. The king was just.

To my mind this indefinitness is to rouse our curiosity and open up multiple suggestions our minds are prone to accept. But no, the speaker is now definite to set at rest your curiosity.

So logically indefinite is made definite in the narrative that follows. As "a king" in my narrative is "the king", so is your ' a final warning'. Another issue is that there are thousands of such final warnings in the world; it is one of them. We would make it definite hereafter....